# Finding file with date specific for copy with Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible

I'm looking to have Ansible to pickup N-1 DIR i.e. current date -1 (Yesterday file) and pickup those files to copy the data to target location.

I wrote something like below but it is failing at `latest_file`:

```
  - name: List
    command: "hdfs dfs -ls /data/files"
    register: hdfs_dir_list
  - debug: var=hdfs_dir_list.stdout_lines
  - name: Retrieve
    set_fact:
    latest_file: "{{ hdfs_dir_list.files | sort(attribute='date -1') | last }}"
  - name: Copy
    command: hadoop distcp "hdfs:///data/{{hdfs_dir_list}}" "/data/{{hdfs_dir_list}}"
```

Not sure what is wrong. Can you please help what is missing in this code to achieve my goal?

Comment: `latest_file` in the `set_fact` task needs to be indented, but that may not fix everything. Can you please post the errors you are receiving (after fixing the indentation) as well as the contents of the `hdfs_dir_list` variable?

Comment: Sure, Pls find below info.

Comment: ERROR! 'latest_file' is not a valid attribute for a Task

The error appears to be in '/dir/test_copy.yml': line 15, column 15, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  - debug: var=hdfs_dir_list.stdout_lines
              ^ here

There appears to be both 'k=v' shorthand syntax and YAML in this task. Only one syntax may be used.

This error can be suppressed as a warning using the "invalid_task_attribute_failed" configuration

Comment: Please make sure you add extra information to the question for visibility. Your current error can be fixed by changing the `debug` task to `- debug: var=hdfs_dir_list["stdout_lines"]`, or by using full YAML syntax

Answer (score 1):

`latest_file` is not a task level parameter but a parameter of the `set_fact` module. So you need to indent it correctly. Always remember that yaml has sytactically significant new lines and indentations, as explained on this [short straightforward tutorial](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/)

> [Yaml is] a strict superset of JSON, with the addition of syntactically significant newlines and indentation, like Python. Unlike Python, however, YAML doesn’t allow literal tab characters for indentation.

Moreover, as stated in @Matt P comment, you should adopt the yaml only syntax wherever possible and drop the old `key=value` shorthand syntax.

Lastly (while I'm at it), the good practice checker [`ansible-lint`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint) would report that:

- `All tasks should be named`
- `Commands should not change things if nothing needs doing`
- `Variables should have spaces before and after: {{ var_name }}`

Although you may have other logic problems to fix afterwards, this is how to modify your example tasks to get something syntactically correct and respecting the latest ansible good practice:

```
  - name: List
    command: "hdfs dfs -ls /data/files"
    register: hdfs_dir_list
    changed_when: false

  - name: Debug registered var
    debug:
      var: hdfs_dir_list.stdout_lines

  - name: Retrieve latest file from output
    set_fact:
      latest_file: "{{ hdfs_dir_list.files | sort(attribute='date -1') | last }}"

  - name: Copy
    command: hadoop distcp "hdfs:///data/{{ hdfs_dir_list }}" "/data/{{ hdfs_dir_list }}"
    # Set the following if copying the file once is ok
    creates: "/data/{{ hdfs_dir_list }}"
    # If not set a changed_when rule bases on command result
    register: copy_result
    changed_when: <add a check on copy_result saying when command is in changed state>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer . is my sort(attribute='date -1') correct to look current date minus one date(yesterday). ?

Comment: Rhetoric question: do you have an attribute named `"date-1"` in your hash list `hdfs_dir_list.files` that you can use to sort it?